# How to stop auto-capitalization of verbose_name in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to prevent Django from auto-capitalizing of the verbose_name in models? E.g:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    enb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name="eNB ID", blank=True)
```

I want to handle the capitalization myself and display "eNB ID" instead of "ENB ID" anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the simple workaround for this is adding a whitespace at the beginning of `verbose_name`. Function that performs the capitalization (`capfirst`) changes only the first letter. If it is a whitespace nothing will be changed. Because web browsers ignore consecutive whitespaces everything will be displayed correctly.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    enb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name=" eNB ID", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = " test model"
```

Comment: This also works for a Model's verbose_name in the Meta subclass.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that [Django capitalizes the first letter when setting the form field for that model field](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L456):

```
...
defaults = {
    'required': not self.blank,
    'label': capfirst(self.verbose_name),
    'help_text': self.help_text
}
```

You could create your own custom model field that overwrites the `capfirst` (by passing the label as kwarg):

```
from django.db import models
class UpcappedModelField(models.Field):

    def formfield(self, form_class=forms.CharField, **kwargs):
        return super(UpcappedModelField, self).formfield(form_class=forms.CharField, 
                         label=self.verbose_name, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Overriding all model fields seams like too much effort.

Comment: @danihp A model fields `__init__` doesn't accept `label`, as label is a Form field concept. It's present in the `formfield` definition because it's being passed onto the Form field's constructor

Comment: +1. This is the kind of answer that denotes deep knowledge from user, but nobody votes up.

Answer (score 1):

Adding verbose_name in Meta class works for me.

```
from django.db import models

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Artist", max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Artist"
        verbose_name_plural = "aRTiStS"
```

result:
[image]

Comment: That's the model's name, not a field name

Answer (score 0):

if one needs all fields names to start with first character lowercase (e.g. in create forms), this can be set for label in css:

```
label:first-letter {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "most correct" answer in modern Django (v1.11+) is to do the following:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('field name'), blank=True)


class TestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'field_name': _('field name')
        }
```

This doesn't require you to define a custom *model* field just to change the *form*, use custom CSS, or hack around browser behavior. It's laser-targeted to *only* change the string that gets sent to the form renderer for that one field, with absolutely no other potential knock-on effects.