# consisten (un)capitalization of labels in rendering of form fields

Tags: django-forms

My graphic design requires all fields in HTML forms to be lowercase. Example:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_pressure_Hg">pressure Hg</label></th><td><input 
id="id_pressure_Hg" type="text" name="pressure_Hg" /></td></tr>
```

Django forms, however, per default make my labels with capital first letter. Since I have a lot of fields and many forms are created from a model (through a modelform), the "label" attribute is not a viable solution.

Is there a way to modify the function which translates field names into field labels?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000063/how-to-stop-auto-capitalization-of-verbose-name-in-django

is the same question, a workaround is presented there

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

example..

in your forms.py

```
value = forms.CharField(label=u'', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

in your HTML file.

```
<ul>
    <li>value Value : {{form.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

you can modify the `form.value` in your CSS or JQuery. i has this attribute as an input in html.. `id=id_value` and `name=value`