# Django always capitalizes a model's verbose name in admin index page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

There's a similar question concerning a field's `verbose_name`: [How to stop auto-capitalization of verbose_name in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000063/how-to-stop-auto-capitalization-of-verbose-name-in-django)

When listing available models of an app in the admin index page, Django always capitalizes the first letter of the model's `verbose_name_plural` and use it as the model's name.

Here's the code from [django.contrib.admin.sites.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L404):

```
model_dict = {
    'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),
    'perms': perms,
}
```

But consider the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG5aL.png), I want to display "vCenters" instead of "VCenters".

I can remove the `capfirst`, and explicitly capitalize other models' `verbose_name_plural` to make it work.

But I have to change django's source code and it doesn't seem to be a bug of Django. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: You could subclass AdminSite and modify its add_index function to your needs. So you wont have to touch the source code.

Comment: Besides overriding the not so short `index` method of `AdminSite`, you have to know the internals of the admin site to plug your subclass in. @andre's answer seems legitimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy...

- Make a copy of the `admin/index.html` template to your
  `template/admin/index.html`
- Create your own template filter: `lowerfirst_if_starts_with_v` in your
  own `templatetags/my_special_thing.py` directory

```py
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def lowerfirst_if_starts_with_v(value):
    """Lowercase the first character of the value."""
    return value and value[0] =='v' and value[0].lower() + value[1:]
```

- Load it in the `index.html`

```
{%load my_special_thing%}
```

- Apply it to `index.html` on line `23`

```html
<th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}"> \
{{ model.name|lowerfirst_if_starts_with_v }}</a></th>
```

And done.